# File based configuration handling in C (Unix)

Tags: c, parsing, unix, configuration

This is probably one of the most common tasks / problems when programming; You need to store the configuration of your application somewhere.

While I'm trying to create a webserver or other applications, I'd like to keep the code as clean as possible since my main interest in programming is architecture. This results in me wanting to store configurations in a file which can be changed without having to re-compile the software.

I'm not here to re-invent the wheel or anything like that, so what I'd like to do is creating a Configuration reader in C on *nix. The configuration might look a lot like any other software's configuration; Apache, vsftpd, MySQL, etc.

The basic question is: How do you read from a textfile and process each line efficiently (in pure C)? Do I need to use `fgetc()` and process each char?

Comment: XML.  Ick.  That's a LOT of overhead for a simple ini file.

Comment: Indeed my thought. And it needs to be pure C and not use any external libraries. So i want to learn how to do this :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so let's hit the other part.  You need to think about what you'd like to have as your "language".  In the UNIX world, the sort of canonical version is probably whitespace-delimited text (think `/etc/hosts`) or ":" delimited text (like `/etc/passwd`).

You have a couple of options, the simplest in some sense being to use scanf(3).  Again, read the man page for details, but if a line entry is something like

```
port    100
```

then you'll be looking for something like

```
char inbuf[MAXLINE];
int  val;

scanf("%s %d\n", &inbuf[0], &val);
```

You can get a bit more flexibility if you write a simple FSA parse: read characters one at a time from the line, and use a finite automaton to define what to do.

Comment: Thank you, this and your other posts address what i want!

Comment: This is vulnerable to buffer overflow if the field is longer than MAXLINE, right?

Comment: Yeah. And?  This is, after all, a discussion of making a config file.

Comment: @CharlieMartin "Yeah. And? This is, after all, a discussion of making a config file." aaand here is your exploit. Nearly all configuration files are, by definition, exposed to the outside world and they can be modified in any way by the users and other 3rd party programs. So it's not merely a discussion of making a config file "after all". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c for how to use `scanf` properly.

Comment: @boramalper So, yes, you're right, I didn't talk about buffer overflow vulnerabilities while explaining to a new programmer how to read a basic text file. I didn't explain endianness either. Or segmentation faults.

I've often noticed that one of my advantages teaching programming is that I still remember when I didn't know everything.

Comment: @CharlieMartin I don't know what made you think that the author is a "new programmer" as I cannot see any indicators of that in the question, but nevertheless, why teach things the wrong way in the very first place? Endianness aside (presuming the we are not moving configuration files around), buffer overflows and segmentation faults are also a bug right in the software and not just a security issue which you should be concerned with only later. What if a path in the config is longer than `MAXLINE`, considering that it will also be *indented* with tabs (or worse, spaces) as well.

Comment: @boramalper the part where he asks if he needs to use `fgetc` or what.

Answer (score 13):

Hmmm there is [LibConfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/).

I have found it in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file)

Comment: Well this is a very nice Library, which i would probably use if i didnt want to learn about the underlying structure.

Answer (score 12):

Various people have given reasonably good advice - the Pure-FTP example is interesting.

You should also read [TAOUP](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/) (The Art of Unix Programming) by E S Raymond.  It has examples a-plenty of configuration files.  It also outlines canonical idioms for the configuration files.  For example, you should probably allow '#' to start a comment to the end of the line, and ignore blank lines.  You should also decide what you will do if the configuration file contains a line you don't understand - whether to ignore and continue silently, or whether to complain.  (I prefer things that complain; then I know why what I've just added isn't having any effect - whereas silent ignoring means I don't know whether the entry I just added has any effect.)

Another problem is locating the configuration file.  Do you do that by compiled-in location, by a default install location with environment variable to override, or by some other piece of magic?  Make sure there's a command line option to allow the configuration file to be specified absolutely - even consider making that the only way to do it.

Otherwise, within broad limits, keep it simple and everyone will be happier.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, here's a real example of C code:

```
/* demo-fgets -- read a "demo.text", copy to stdout with line
   numbers. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINE 100

FILE * fp;
char bufr[MAXLINE];

extern int errno ;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int count = 0 ;
    if((fp = fopen("demo.text","r")) != NULL){
        /* then file opened successfully. */
        while(fgets(bufr,MAXLINE,fp)!=NULL){
            /* then no read error */
            count +=1;
            printf("%d: %s",     /* no "\n", why? */
                   count, bufr);
        }
        /* fgets returned null */
        if(errno != 0){
            perror(argv[0]);    /* argv[0]?  Why that? */
            exit(1);
        }
        exit(0);                /* EOF found, normal exit */
    } else {                    /* there was an error on open */
        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I run it with this input file:

```
520 $ cat demo.text 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
aliquet augue id quam. Sed a metus. Quisque sit amet quam. Sed id
ante. In egestas est non mi. Sed vel velit non elit vehicula
viverra. Curabitur eget tortor in ipsum vulputate
faucibus. Suspendisse imperdiet mauris at nibh. Sed interdum. Maecenas
vulputate, massa vel placerat mattis, ante est tincidunt sem, in
sollicitudin velit lacus non tortor. Etiam sagittis consequat nisl. 

Vestibulum id leo quis mauris gravida placerat. Donec aliquet justo a
tortor. Etiam nisi nibh, auctor non, luctus et, aliquam vitae,
metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc lacinia quam a ligula. Nulla quis nisi eu
nunc imperdiet cursus. Nunc vitae nisi vitae tellus posuere
sollicitudin. Nunc suscipit, dui ac interdum euismod, pede nisl varius
dui, sed mattis libero mauris eu felis. Nam mattis dui eget
nunc. Suspendisse malesuada, pede eget posuere pellentesque, neque
eros pretium nibh, ut blandit dui leo dapibus orci. Etiam lacinia
lectus at orci. Donec ligula lacus, sagittis nec, sodales et,
fringilla lobortis, eros. Etiam sit amet nulla. Aliquam mollis pede id
enim. Etiam ligula felis, pulvinar nec, vestibulum molestie, interdum
ut, urna. Ut porta ullamcorper diam. Nullam interdum arcu. 

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam eu enim quis sem accumsan
tristique. Proin non sem. Etiam quis ante. Aenean ornare pellentesque
dolor. Praesent sodales. Cras dui velit, scelerisque a, accumsan a,
vestibulum in, dui. Pellentesque sed sapien. Etiam augue est,
convallis eget, egestas vel, molestie id, turpis. Cum sociis natoque
penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Cras posuere lorem eu diam. Ut ultricies velit. Nunc imperdiet
suscipit mauris. Vestibulum molestie elit id risus. Phasellus et
purus. Vestibulum id mauris. Fusce gravida elit quis turpis. Aliquam
ut est. 

Sed in mauris eu nulla rhoncus suscipit. Nam id dolor sit amet turpis
placerat sodales. Nunc ipsum. Quisque diam tellus, dapibus non,
interdum at, aliquam sit amet, tellus. Donec non pede eget massa
aliquam semper. Quisque dictum lacinia ipsum. Fusce magna purus,
mattis id, commodo et, lobortis eu, arcu. Vestibulum viverra neque a
nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque vel felis in ligula blandit
auctor. Quisque quam. Curabitur turpis. Morbi molestie augue a
nisi. Nulla sollicitudin sagittis elit. Suspendisse in odio sed magna
dictum vestibulum. Duis facilisis lorem eget neque. Proin sit amet
urna eget velit scelerisque aliquam. Pellentesque imperdiet. Nullam
sapien. Nullam placerat ipsum eget metus. 

Mauris ornare risus eu velit. Morbi bibendum diam in sem. Morbi
aliquet nisl sit amet quam. Donec ornare sagittis nibh. Fusce ac
lectus. Sed sit amet risus. Integer facilisis commodo
sem. Pellentesque facilisis. Donec libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: Looks very good. How would you suggest you process each line?
Imagine the fist line might be PORT=1000  would you somehow create a function that would return that line and the value as a struct? This might be more fundamentals about "architecture" than pure "how to".

Comment: Why is bufr not a local variable?  It perfectly well could be - and therefore (in my book) should be.  I'd also use sizeof(bufr) in the fgets() call.  I'd also test for failure and exit to avoid the distant else clause.  I'd also close the file, in case the code gets ripped out into a function. Etc.

Comment: Okay, Filip, I've thought about it for at least five minutes, and I'm completely at a loss to understand why you're prefer to have a fixed buffer allocated on the stack instead of in data space where overflows won't pee in your return codes.  As to the others points, meh.  Whatever.

Comment: @Jonathan, having the buffer as a local variable is argumentative. He most likely used it to simplify the example.

Comment: Oops. sorry, Filip, that was argument with jonathan.  Many apologies.

Comment: Note that the line `extern int errno;` leads to undefined behaviour in C90 or later.  To declare `errno` correctly, use `#include <errno.h>`.  See [§7.4 Errors `<errno.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5): _If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program defines an identifier with the name errno, the behavior is undefined._. (That's from C11, but even C90 contains comparable wording.)

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways.  You *don't* need to use fgetc.  You should probably read the stdio man page, but the canonical thing would be to open the file with fopen(3), then read using fgets(3) to read a line at a time.  That would look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * fp ;
char bufr[MAXLINE];

if((fp = fopen(filename, "r") != NULL){
    while(! feof(fp)){
         fgets(bufr, MAXLINE, fp);
         /* Do stuff */
    }
} else {
    /* error processing, couldn't open file */
}
```

You could also look at [libini](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libini) at Sourceforge.

Comment: Ah i see, so it's like using fgets in ASM ( which i've worked with before ). Was a little curious if it was possible to use it with a file-stream.

Thanks, very much appreciated!

Comment: However, I'd like to know how to read to the "next line", do i need to create that myself? There's no "readline" which reads to a \n ? or to any other token

Comment: Im however not completely sattisfied with the answer, since it does not really provide how i do the other managing efficient :)

Comment: fgets is a read line.  When you do fgets, the "file pointer" advances past the next newline.  The loop I show above will read a file line by line.  Just a sec and I'll put up a real example.

Comment: Oh i see, sorry for not understanding that! Very good answer!

Comment: Waaay late here, but there's a huge flaw in this answer.  See [**Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 6):

Why would you *ever* write this code from scratch, it's been done *so* many times; just find a good F/OSS implementation and use that.

> How do you read from a Textfile and process each line efficiently

Don't worry about efficiency, it doesn't matter for reading configuration files. Go for simplicity and maintainability instead.

Comment: Well to be honest we have an assignment in a course at my univ. where we need to create an application but i don't want to store configuration in the applicaton, so i want to go a step further. That's why. And to learn, i want to do it from scratch,how much knowledge would i gain from using pre-made

Comment: Oh and by the way, "Efficient" is kind of abstract, when i use "efficiently" i mean Simplicity + Readabillity and other aspects. I also not want it to take forever to process of course :)

Comment: can't even imaging why it was down voted, even for homework it's valid and most efficient advice here ...

Comment: It doesnt provide anything that i asked for in my question so i can't see why it would ever be upvoted.

Comment: Paul Betts' answer is the best advice: change the specifications because they are wrong. Often, this is what we must tell to people, even if it makes them angry.

Answer (score 4):

The way I would have done it (pseudo-code):

```
while(there is input) {
  get one line;
  if (it is empty line || it beings with spaces followed by a '#') {
    skip this line, either empty or it's a comment;
  }
  find the position of the token that splits option name and its value;
  copy the option name and its value to separate variables;
  removing spaces before and after these variables if necessary;
  if (option == option1) {
     parse value for option 1;
  } else if (option == option2) {
     parse value for option 2;
  } else {
     handle unknown option name;
  }
  check consistency of options if necessary;
}
```

Note that part of the code (checking for empty lines, comments, and spaces around variables) is there to give you extra flexibility when writing the config file. For example, you won't crash your program by accidentally leaving an extra space here and there.

This is assuming you have config files that look like the following:

```
# comment for option 1
option1 = value1

# comment for option 2
option2 = value2

...
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution - [Pure-ftpd](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.Configuration-File)

> Unlike many daemons, Pure-FTPd doesn't read any configuration file. Instead, it uses command-line options. ... Adding a parser for configuration files in the server is a bad
>   idea. It slows down everything and needs resources for nothing.

And for options there is [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Getopt.html)

Comment: Dead link now. I don't get the point though - configuration-file-reading is a quick one-time-penalty in the startup. Afterwards, accessing the options should be equally fast no matter if they came from the disk or the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [getline() function and friends](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Line-Input.html) in GNU LibC

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a clean, dependency-less, event-driven INI file parser in C a while ago. I've decided to throw it into a [public Hg repository](http://projects.stoneship.org/hg/shared/alini/). It is MIT-licenced, so you're free to use it any where you like.

Answer (score 2):

C is not easy as Python, yet we still want something like "import"...

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*conf*/
/*
 * #ip
 * ip:192.168.0.0.1
 * #port
 * port:8888
 * */
/*read conf*/
void test()
{
        FILE *fp = fopen("conf", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
                return;
        }

        char line[1024] = { 0 };
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
                memset(line, 0, 1024);
                fgets(line, 1024, fp);
                if (line[0] == '#')
                {
                        continue;
                }

                int len = strlen(line);
                char *pos = strchr(line, ':');
                if (pos == NULL)
                {
                        continue;
                }
                char key[64] = { 0 };
                char val[64] = { 0 };

                int offset = 1;
                if (line[len - 1] == '\n')
                {
                        offset = 2;
                }

                strncpy(key, line, pos - line);
                strncpy(val, pos + 1, line + len - offset - pos);

                printf("%s -> %s\n", key, val);
        }
}

int main()
{
        printf("read start...\n");
        test();
        printf("read success!!!\n");
        int c = getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

The above based on conf formated in x:y...

```
ip:192.168.0.0.1
port:8888
```

Comment: This answer should have more ups. I've tested it and it is more functional considering handling comments and LFs.

Comment: But you probably want to *fclose* the file in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider of storing config values as environment variables? :)
And config file will be a shell script you run before your program. (actually shell script will execute it to save variables). That way you are using shell as config parser :)

Use http://www.google.com/codesearch and "read config"

See [Example for httpd][1]

[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20120519035457/http://www.google.com:80/codesearch/p?hl=ru#W6G7kfsfmHo/httpd-2.2.4/server/config.c&q=read config httpd

Comment: It's not been considered and it feels "unsafe" since it makes the application less portable, right?

Comment: Why not? You could use them on unix/win/mac. Just google "environment variable mac" or unix, win.

Comment: Yeah, but you'd have to set all the envoirnment variables, which seems  hard? Or that could maybe be done by programming it..

Comment: It could be set with shell/bat script or any other program. Google: rc.conf - that is example of such config file in FreeBSD.

Comment: Sorry but i don't like it. And the question was not really for alternative configuration types