# How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?

Tags: c, scanf, buffer-overflow

I use this code:

```
while ( scanf("%s", buf) == 1 ){
```

What would be the best way to prevent possible buffer overflow so that it can be passed strings of random lengths?

I know I can limit the input string by calling for example:

```
while ( scanf("%20s", buf) == 1 ){
```

But I'd prefer to be able to process whatever the user inputs.
Or can't this be done safely using `scanf` and I should use `fgets`?

Answer (score 83):

In their book [The Practice of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161586X) (which is well worth reading), Kernighan and Pike discuss this problem, and they solve it by using `snprintf()` to create the string with the correct buffer size for passing to the `scanf()` family of functions.  In effect:

```
int scanner(const char *data, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char format[32];
    if (buflen == 0)
        return 0;
    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds", (int)(buflen-1));
    return sscanf(data, format, buffer);
}
```

Note, this still limits the input to the size provided as 'buffer'.  If you need more space, then you have to do memory allocation, or use a non-standard library function that does the memory allocation for you.

---

Note that the POSIX 2008 (2013) version of the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) family of functions supports a format modifier `m` (an assignment-allocation character) for string inputs (`%s`, `%c`, `%[`).  Instead of taking a `char *` argument, it takes a `char **` argument, and it allocates the necessary space for the value it reads:

```
char *buffer = 0;
if (sscanf(data, "%ms", &buffer) == 1)
{
    printf("String is: <<%s>>\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

If the `sscanf()` function fails to satisfy all the conversion specifications, then all the memory it allocated for `%ms`-like conversions is freed before the function returns.

Comment: @Sam: Yes, it should be `buflen-1` — Thank You.  You then have to worry about unsigned underflow (wrapping to a rather large number), hence the `if` test.  I'd be sorely tempted to replace that with an `assert()`, or back it up with an `assert()` before the `if` that fires during development if anyone is careless enough to pass 0 as the size.  I've not carefully reviewed the documentation for what `%0s` means to `sscanf()` — the test might be better as `if (buflen < 2)`.

Comment: So `snprintf` writes some data to a string buffer, and `sscanf` reads from that created string.  Where exactly does this replace `scanf` in that it reads from stdin?

Comment: It's also quite confusing that you use the word "format" for your result string and thus pass in "format" as the first argument to `snprintf` yet it is not the actual format parameter.

Comment: @krb686: This code is written so that the data to be scanned is in the parameter `data` and hence `sscanf()` is appropriate.  If you want to read from standard input instead, drop the `data` parameter and call `scanf()` instead.  As to the choice of the name `format` for the variable that becomes the format string in the call to `sscanf()`, you are entitled to rename it if you wish, but its name is not inaccurate.  I am not sure what alternative makes sense; would `in_format` make it any clearer? I am not planning to change it in this code; you may if you use this idea in your own code.

Comment: @krb686: Incidentally, the `snprintf()` takes the number in `buflen` (say 256), and creates a string in the variable `format` that is equivalent to `"%255s"`.  Then `sscanf()` reads from the string `data` using `format` as the format string (conversion specification) to control how the data is interpreted, with the result being written into the variable `buffer`. Thus the leading white space in `data` is ignored and the first 'word' is copied to `buffer` without risk of buffer overflow as long as the area pointed at by `buffer` has at least as much space as `buflen` says it has.

Comment: Note also that MSVC at least up to 2013 does not conform to POSIX standards, so the format modifier for "%ms" is not available

Comment: @mabraham: It is still true under macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (up to 2017-06-06) — the `scanf()` on macOS is not documented as supporting `%ms`, useful though it would be.

Answer (score 35):

If you are using gcc, you can use the GNU-extension `a` specifier to have scanf() allocate memory for you to hold the input:

```
int main()
{
  char *str = NULL;

  scanf ("%as", &str);
  if (str) {
      printf("\"%s\"\n", str);
      free(str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** As Jonathan pointed out, you should consult the `scanf` man pages as the specifier might be different (`%m`) and you might need to enable certain defines when compiling.

Comment: That's more an issue of using glibc (the GNU C Library) than of using the GNU C Compiler.

Comment: And note that the POSIX 2008 standard provides the `m` modifier to do the same job.  See [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html). You'll need to check whether the systems you use do support this modifier.

Comment: GNU (as found on Ubuntu 13.10, at any rate) supports `%ms`. The notation `%a` is a synonym for `%f` (on output, it requests hexadecimal floating point data). The GNU man page for `scanf()` says: _ It is not available if the program is compiled with `gcc -std=c99` or gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE (unless `_GNU_SOURCE` is also specified), in which case the `a` is interpreted as a specifier for floating-point numbers (see above)._

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` does the job. The other thing would be to write your own parser, if the input is well formatted. Also note your second example needs a bit of modification to be used safely:

```
#define LENGTH          42
#define str(x)          # x
#define xstr(x)         str(x)

/* ... */ 
int nc = scanf("%"xstr(LENGTH)"[^\n]%*[^\n]", array);
```

The above discards the input stream upto but not including the newline (`\n`) character. You will need to add a `getchar()` to consume this.

Comment: `array` needs to be `char array[LENGTH+1];`

Comment: @RolandIllig You mean for 12 years? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Directly using `scanf(3)` and its variants poses a number of problems. Typically, users and non-interactive use cases are defined in terms of lines of input. It's rare to see a case where, if enough objects are not found, more lines will solve the problem, yet that's the default mode for scanf. (If a user didn't know to enter a number on the first line, a second and third line will probably not help.)

At least if you `fgets(3)` you know how many input lines your program will need, and you won't have any buffer overflows...

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the length of the input is definitely easier. You could accept an arbitrarily-long input by using a loop, reading in a bit at a time, re-allocating space for the string as necessary...

But that's a lot of work, so most C programmers just chop off the input at some arbitrary length. I suppose you know this already, but using fgets() isn't going to allow you to accept arbitrary amounts of text - you're still going to need to set a limit.

Comment: So does anybody know how to do that with scanf then?

Comment: Using fgets in a loop can allow you to accept arbitrary amounts of text - just keep `realloc()`ing your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

**In General:**

- There is no reading function that can read the whole input of a user
  in one call if it exceeds the maximum size a number-variable can
  hold!
- In a 32bit processor the maximum number you can have is 2^32-1 and
  in a 64bit processor the maximum number you can have is 2^64-1.
- Most reading function, if not all use an integer for the size of the
  input and the maximum number you can use there is 2^32-1.

**About [scanf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):**

- If it used inside a loop it ignores spaces and new lines.
- Can be used to detect if the input was an integer.
- It is as harmful as any other function can be, if his/her user
  doesn’t know how to use it properly!

**About [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm):**

- It has no difference when we speak about sizes from [scanf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).
  [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) can also cause buffer overflow if it used incorrectly.
  The reason such conversations are not made about [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) is
  because [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) obliged you to use the size of the input while
  [scanf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) don't but this doesn't mean you shouldn't.
- [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) will also ignore the rest of the input if the user of
  your program exceeded the maximum size the variable n can hold.

**Declaration:**
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* 2^32-1=4294967295 */

int main(){
    /* 2^32-1=4294967295 */

    char *a;
    char *b;

    if ((a=(char *)malloc(4294967295 * sizeof(char)))==NULL){
        puts("Memory could not be Allocated");
        
        return 1;
    }

    fgets(a, 4294967294, stdio);

    a[4294967294]='\0';
    
    if ((b=(char *)malloc(strlen(a) * sizeof(char)))==NULL){
        puts("Memory could not be Allocated");
        
        return 2;
    }
    
    strcpy(b, a);

    free(a);

    printf("%s\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

**Conclusion:**

- My code above is an example why reading with one function call is a bad idea! If someone gave you an input that could be read in one call and you saved it in a single array and after that you wanted to break it into pieces, the saving in the single array was unnecessary from the beginning because you could have read it piece by piece with [scanf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) anyway without storing it first into a single array. You just did extra computations for no reason.

Comment: You might want to add a reference to the POSIX standard `getline()` function

Comment: There is no reason. What i wrote above also includes getLine(). I could go into details about it but there is no reason. As I said all function can be bad, if the user of them doesn't know how to use them properly and the getLine() function is a very good example of it.

Answer (score -1):

It's not that much work to make a function that's allocating the needed memory for your string.
That's a little c-function i wrote some time ago, i always use it to read in strings.

It will return the read string or if a memory error occurs NULL.
But be aware that you have to `free()` your string and always check for its return value.

```
#define BUFFER 32

char *readString()
{
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER), *err;
    int pos;
    for(pos = 0; str != NULL && (str[pos] = getchar()) != '\n'; pos++)
    {
        if(pos % BUFFER == BUFFER - 1)
        {
            if((err = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (BUFFER + pos + 1))) == NULL)
                free(str);
            str = err;
        }
    }
    if(str != NULL)
        str[pos] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is by definition `1`. You don't need it here.

Comment: Usually it's good practise to keep pointer allocation/freeing at the same level, meaning that your function should not allocate memory on its own, since the caller then has to free it. Most of the standard library / posix functions adhere to this principle by either returning a static string (like `strerror(3)`) or expect a pre-allocated string passed in (like (`strerror_r(3)` - or `scanf(3)` ) ...

Comment: This code is not correct by any means. `str[pos] = getchar()` cannot check for the special value EOF being returned from the function.