# File Config, creation and usage in C unix

Tags: c, unix, config

I'm trying to understand how I can create a ".config" file containing a bunch of parameters to later use to set up the variables in my C project on Unix.

I created my ".config" file using `sudo nano test.config` and wrote some stuff inside such as:

```
#N is this
N 10
#p is that
p 0.002
#T is this
T 10
```

Now that I did that how can I read its content and use it to initialize my variables?

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: open the file, read the contents, set variables as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File based Configuration handling in C ( Unix )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411921/file-based-configuration-handling-in-c-unix)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons just like a regular text file?

Comment: Configuration for which project? Show some [MCVE] please

Comment: A file is a file is a file — mostly.  Yes, a configuration file is just a regular text file designated as a configuration file and formatted in some particular manner.  It looks like yours will ignore lines starting with `#` as a comment line, ignore blank lines (for sanity's sake), and expects an alphanumeric keyword and a value.  That much is easy.  Lots of details left to worry about — are spaces significant in the value part; can you quote strings or spaces, what names are important, are there sections in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The several answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411921/841108) question explain how to parse that config file, but you could use standard [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques (perhaps your own [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)) or Glib's [lexical scanning](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Lexical-Scanner.html)  or [key-value pair parser](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html) (or use something else). You certainly should define and *document* (perhaps using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)) what is the [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) of that textual configuration file (and what the various entries there represent: for example, if that configuration file refers to other files, how do you handle spaces in such file paths, etc....). A common (but not universal) convention is to consider as comments so skip any line starting with `#`.

Another question is how to get that config file while running in an arbitrary [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). You just need to build the absolute path of your file (for [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) or [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)), e.g. with

```
char configpath[100];
snprintf(configpath, sizeof(configpath), "%s/.test.config", getenv("HOME"));
```

You could test before that `getenv("HOME")` is not `NULL`, but in practice that is *very* unlikely; see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html); and the case when it gives a very long file path is also unlikely; you might test that [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) returns a count less than `sizeof(configpath)` or use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html).

You might use other functions, e.g. [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) or [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) to get that file path (but you probably should stick to `snprintf` or `asprintf` with `getenv("HOME")`...).

You might consider instead embedding some scriptable interpreter like [lua](http://lua.org/) or [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) in your program (but that is a strong architectural design decision). Then the configuration file becomes some (Turing-complete!) script.

BTW, there is no need to use `sudo` to edit that configuration file (under your home directory), and you might decide to also read some system-wide configuration under `/etc/`